# Can I use the word "arguments" as an argument?

Tags: javascript

Gee, I really want to define my function as:

```
function myFunction(arguments) {}
```

but arguments is

> An Array-like object corresponding to the arguments passed to a
>   function.

But darn it, I really want to reference

```
arguments.a, arguments.b
```

instead of:

```
arguments[0], arguments[1]
```

Comment: If you define a variable "arguments" in your function you just override the "default" one. Yes, you can.

Comment: what if you have more than 26 arguments?

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work.  One solution might be to call it Arguments instead of arguments.

Comment: arguments is not reserved, so yes, you should be able to use it, but why would you ?

Comment: @AtifMohammedAmeenuddin, I see your point: because there are no letters after z!

Comment: @adeneo, in the other programming language that I use quite often, we address arguments as arguments.a and arguments.b.

Comment: Javascript is not like "other programming languages" ;)

Comment: So it's not the word itself you're asking about, but how to access the arguments with dot notation.

Comment: @adeneo `arguments` as a parameter name is not permitted in the strict language. If you want to give advice for the default language, go ahead, but I don't think we should be doing that.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - okay, it just wasn't on [the list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) !

Comment: So I guess I can use JavaScript case sensitivity as a force for good instead of evil for once.

Comment: Why is it so important to call the parameter "arguments"?

Comment: @adeneo Rule 4h [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Api16Q7VQGPddExwT2xjQ3Zacm9JcTE3NWpDOWdDN2c#gid=0)

Comment: @adeneo is right, it is not a **reserved** keyword, but in **strict mode** it won't work(like using eval as a parameter or renaming it).

Comment: @Juhana, it's a matter of taste.  I just like the taste of calling it arguments.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - you got me curious, why should we suddenly only post advice and answers that adhere to strict mode ?

Comment: @Phillip: You are entitled to program however you see fit, but god help me if I ever have to maintain something of yours with `arguments`. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm asking here on StackOverflow first.  I think my solution is to call it aRgUmEnTs or ArGuMeNtS or something like that.

Comment: @Phillip if you're not writing a script in strict mode you can safely use `arguments` as a parameter name. Otherwise you will need something like `Arguments`, `$arguments` or `_arguments`. Or, shortly, `args` ;)

Comment: @adeneo Do you understand why the strict language is opt-in instead of being enabled by default?

Comment: Yes I do, but you're saying we shouldn't give advice for the default language, but that we should always adhere to strict mode, and I'm really wondering why ?

Comment: @adeneo Because we want everybody to write code that is compatible with the strict language. Everybody. Without exception. We want OP to write strict code. Therefore, `arguments` as a parameter name is out of the question.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - why on earth would we want that, it's opt-in for a reason ?

Comment: @adeneo As I thought. You don't understand why it's opt-in. It's opt-in because making it default would "break the web", i.e. existing old code that is not compatible with the strict language would break.

Comment: Nope, it's opt-in because it's only supported in the latest browsers, and it breaks in IE9 etc. so for real life production code, it's not an option.

Comment: @adeneo What are you talking about? The strict language does not break in IE9. The strict language is a **subset of the default language**. It works everywhere, even in IE6.

Comment: Well, not break, doesn't work as it's ignored. I don't use it very often, and I see no reason to start using it everywhere, but that's my opinion.

Comment: And I see no reason why answers should suddenly always adhere to a subset opt-in standard, that's just stupid!

Comment: @adeneo Using the `'use strict';` directive and writing code that is compatible with the strict language are two different things. OK, you don't use the directive, fine. I don't mind. But you **should** write code that is compatible with the strict language. Everybody should. That's my point. If someone (like OP in this case) wants to use `arguments` as a parameter name, we should advise him not to do that, as that's not compatible with the strict language.

Comment: In my opinion we should advise against it because it's plain stupid. There are a gazillion other names to choose from, so why choose one that is already used for something. I'm not going to complain everytime a question has code with globals being defined directly, or using `caller`, `callee` or just trying to `delete` something etc. just because it's not strict, I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you most certainly can name an argument "arguments", but the real question is *why*.

Short example from the Chrome console:

```
> function a(arguments){console.log(arguments.a);}
> a({a:1,b:2})
1
> a("cow")
undefined
```

Not the best solution.

Now, you could, in theory, do some sort of mapping:

```
function foo()
{
   var argMap = ['a','b']
   for(var i = 0; i < argMap.length; i++)
       arguments[argMap[i]] = arguments[i];
   console.log(arguments.a);
}

foo('a is first')
// console logs 'a is first'
```

But again... why?

What you cannot do is grab all of the variables defined in a given context: there is no equivalent to Python's `locals`. JS just isn't built that way. So I recommend:

```
function foo(a,b){
    console.log(a);
}
```

Comment: Oh, and if you think it a good idea to name an argument "arguments" and you're working with another programmer, it will be ensured that you will not sleep well at night.

Comment: I think I'm going to call it Arguments if the object contains lowercase field names, and ARGUMENTS if the object contains uppercase field names .  I sometimes get uppercase field names back from a SQL query.

Comment: @Phillip I think you're better off calling them params.

Answer (score 1):

```
function foo (params) {
    // params.a
    // params.b
}
```

Usage:

```
foo({ a: 123, b: 456 });
```

Comment: Can I rename params to arguments?

Comment: Which part of this answers the question?

Comment: If it said function foo (Arguments), that would answer the question.

Comment: @Juhana I'm providing advice. OP should stop considering the `arguments` name as it is incompatible with the strict language.

Comment: I think I'm going to use ARGUMENTS.  This is particularly true when my ajax calls return the results in an object that contains uppercase field names.

Comment: @Phillip Why do you insist on such a long name? Why not just `args`?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, company standards.  We use the word arguments to connote the scope.

Comment: @Phillip As already stated on this page, the name `arguments` has been restricted in the latest edition of JavaScript. Your company should update its JavaScript code conventions.

Answer (score 1):

How about this, taken from **Šime Vidas** answer

```
function myArgs() {
    arguments = arguments[0];
    console.log(arguments);
}

myArgs({a: 1,b: 2});
```